# How do I use complex functions in Excel 2003 VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a custom function in Excel VBA using the complex number functions from the Analysis ToolPak VBA add-in.   If I assign `c = imSum(a, b)` I get a popup error "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined."   If I change it to `c = WorksheetFunction.imSum(a, b)` (as what little I've found on this led me to try) I do not get the popup error but I get a #VALUE error in the cell.  Changing the method name to something bogus creates the same result.  I have both "Analysis ToolPak" and "Analysis ToolPak - VBA" add-ins checked in Excel but in the VBA add-in manager there are none listed at all.  Is this a syntax thing or a missing module thing?

UPDATE...
I got this working using the simple format `c = imSum(a, b)` after checking "atvbaen.xls" in the references window. I also ran the command `AddIns.Add("atvbaen.xls").Installed = True` though I have no idea if this helped.  Couldn't get `[imSum(a, b)]` evaluation or `Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum(a, b)` to work.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: that's it.  Function ctest(a, b)
    ctest = WorksheetFunction.imSumx(a, b)
End Function

Comment: there's an "x" too much: change `imSumx`  to `imSum`

Comment: mentioned that in the question, changed to to `imSumx` to show that there was no error popup from an unknown method, same #VALUE error as `imSum`.  `IMSUM` and `imsum` same thing

Comment: the code works for me, are you sure you are entering the proper criteria?

Comment: do you have anything in addin manager?  guessing this is my problem

Comment: In the VBA Editor, under `Tools` ► `References`, is there anything marked `missing` or any strange entries?

Comment: no.  I checked previously unchecked `atvbaen.xls` per suggestion below but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, but are you using Excel 2003? If you're not, you don't need to worry about the Analysis ToolPak/VBA ToolPak being installed as these functions are all built in (in fact, I'd uninstall them if you have them there).

If you're using Excel 2003, you need to have the VBA ATP installed and also you need to go into the references for your VBA project and check "atpvbaen.xls".

Comment: yes I am.  prefer the tiny buttons on 2003.  I found this reference and checked it but it didn't change anything.  Still have empty add-in manager.  had high hopes, maybe this is a needed step but still not there.  how did you even know about this cryptic reference?!

Comment: have it working now but hard to tell if this helped.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the worksheet, `IMSUM()` takes strings as input so in *VBA*:

```
Public Function whatever(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    s3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum(s1, s2)
    whatever = "Hello " & s3 & " World"
End Function
```

[image]

If you can't use `IMSUB()` in a worksheet cell, then there is little chance that *VBA* will be able to find it either.

**EDIT#1:**

Subs allow better debugging than UDFs.  Try this sub and tell us what happens:

```
Sub HelpMePlease()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String

    s1 = "1+1i"
    s2 = "2+2i"
    s3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum(s1, s2)
    MsgBox s3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I've copied this exactly and get the same #VALUE error.  If I delete the second line and change the third line from `s3` to `s1` then I get `Hello 12-23i World`, so clearly the problem is my VBA analysis toolpak.  Not sure what to do now

Comment: and yes I can use `IMSUM` and `IMSUB` just fine in Excel, just not in VBA apparantly

Comment: @robisrob  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: run time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method - so pretty clear I don't have the add-in

Comment: I hate when a problem solves itself without my understanding it.  I have it working now for `c = imSum(s1, s2)` but not `c= Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum(s1, s2)` or `c = [imSum(s1, s2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to evaluate them :

```
o = [IMSUM(A1,B1)]
```

or

```
a = "12+34i"
b = "67-89i"
c = Evaluate("IMSUM(" & a & "," & b & ")")
```

Comment: interesting approach but wasn't necessary and was difficult to work with.  usually returned a zero